# wlan0 no listado en arch

Tags: archlinux

```
~]$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:5c:8e:d5:5a:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
```

Este es el último kernel

```
~]$ uname -a
Linux x540sa 5.14.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 22 Sep 2021 21:35:11 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Agradecido si alguien sabe porque no lista la interfaz inalámbrica